# Tensorflow gives different console output, and is slower for some reason

Tags: python, tensorflow

Since today tensorflow seems to output the entire model per epoch for some reason. I am breaking my head over this problem and have no idea what to do.

Epoch 1/12
iterator: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
iterator_1: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential_conv2d_conv2d_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential_conv2d_biasadd_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential_conv2d_1_conv2d_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential_conv2d_1_biasadd_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential_conv2d_2_conv2d_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential_conv2d_2_biasadd_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential_dense_matmul_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential_dense_biasadd_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential_dense_1_matmul_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential_dense_1_biasadd_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential_dense_2_matmul_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential_dense_2_biasadd_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
assignaddvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
assignaddvariableop_1_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_cast_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_cast_2_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_cast_3_readvariableop_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_resourceapplyadam_m: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_resourceapplyadam_v: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_1_resourceapplyadam_m: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_1_resourceapplyadam_v: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_2_resourceapplyadam_m: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_2_resourceapplyadam_v: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_3_resourceapplyadam_m: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_3_resourceapplyadam_v: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_4_resourceapplyadam_m: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_4_resourceapplyadam_v: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_5_resourceapplyadam_m: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_5_resourceapplyadam_v: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_6_resourceapplyadam_m: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_6_resourceapplyadam_v: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_7_resourceapplyadam_m: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_7_resourceapplyadam_v: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_8_resourceapplyadam_m: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_8_resourceapplyadam_v: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_9_resourceapplyadam_m: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_9_resourceapplyadam_v: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_10_resourceapplyadam_m: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_10_resourceapplyadam_v: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_11_resourceapplyadam_m: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
adam_adam_update_11_resourceapplyadam_v: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
assignaddvariableop_2_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
assignaddvariableop_3_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
assignaddvariableop_4_resource: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
IteratorGetNext: (IteratorGetNext): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
ExpandDims: (ExpandDims): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/conv2d/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/conv2d/Conv2D: (Conv2D): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/conv2d/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/conv2d/BiasAdd: (BiasAdd): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/conv2d/Relu: (Relu): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/max_pooling2d/MaxPool: (MaxPool): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/conv2d_1/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/conv2d_1/Conv2D: (Conv2D): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/conv2d_1/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/conv2d_1/BiasAdd: (BiasAdd): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/conv2d_1/Relu: (Relu): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/max_pooling2d_1/MaxPool: (MaxPool): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/conv2d_2/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/conv2d_2/Conv2D: (Conv2D): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/conv2d_2/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/conv2d_2/BiasAdd: (BiasAdd): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/conv2d_2/Relu: (Relu): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/max_pooling2d_2/MaxPool: (MaxPool): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/flatten/Reshape: (Reshape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/dense/MatMul/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/dense/MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/dense/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/dense/BiasAdd: (BiasAdd): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/dense/Sigmoid: (Sigmoid): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/dense_1/MatMul/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/dense_1/MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/dense_1/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/dense_1/BiasAdd: (BiasAdd): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/dense_1/Tanh: (Tanh): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/dense_2/MatMul/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/dense_2/MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/dense_2/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/dense_2/BiasAdd: (BiasAdd): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/Cast: (Cast): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/sub: (Sub): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/clip_by_value/Minimum: (Minimum): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/clip_by_value: (Maximum): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/add: (AddV2): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/Log: (Log): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/mul: (Mul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/sub_1: (Sub): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/sub_2: (Sub): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/add_1: (AddV2): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/Log_1: (Log): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/mul_1: (Mul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/add_2: (AddV2): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/Neg: (Neg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/Mean: (Mean): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Mul: (Mul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Sum: (Sum): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/num_elements: (Size): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/num_elements/Cast: (Cast): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Sum_1: (Sum): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/value: (DivNoNan): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Shape: (Shape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
strided_slice: (StridedSlice): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Cast: (Cast): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Mul: (Mul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Sum: (Sum): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
AssignAddVariableOp: (AssignAddVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Sum_1: (Sum): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
AssignAddVariableOp_1: (AssignAddVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/value/BroadcastGradientArgs: (BroadcastGradientArgs): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/value/div_no_nan: (DivNoNan): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/value/Sum: (Sum): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/value/Reshape: (Reshape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/value/Neg: (Neg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/value/div_no_nan_1: (DivNoNan): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/value/div_no_nan_2: (DivNoNan): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/value/mul: (Mul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/value/Sum_1: (Sum): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/value/Reshape_1: (Reshape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Reshape: (Reshape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Tile: (Tile): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Reshape_1: (Reshape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Shape: (Shape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Tile_1: (Tile): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Mul: (Mul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Shape: (Shape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/add: (AddV2): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/mod: (FloorMod): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/range: (Range): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Fill: (Fill): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/DynamicStitch: (DynamicStitch): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Reshape: (Reshape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/BroadcastTo: (BroadcastTo): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Shape_2: (Shape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Shape_3: (Shape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Prod: (Prod): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Prod_1: (Prod): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Maximum: (Maximum): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/floordiv: (FloorDiv): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Cast: (Cast): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/truediv: (RealDiv): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Neg: (Neg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/add_2/Shape: (Shape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/add_2/Shape_1: (Shape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/add_2/BroadcastGradientArgs: (BroadcastGradientArgs): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/add_2/Sum: (Sum): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/add_2/Reshape: (Reshape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/add_2/Sum_1: (Sum): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/add_2/Reshape_1: (Reshape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/mul/Shape: (Shape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/mul/Shape_1: (Shape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/mul/BroadcastGradientArgs: (BroadcastGradientArgs): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/mul/Mul: (Mul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/mul/Sum: (Sum): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/mul/Reshape: (Reshape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/mul_1/Shape: (Shape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/mul_1/Shape_1: (Shape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/mul_1/BroadcastGradientArgs: (BroadcastGradientArgs): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/mul_1/Mul: (Mul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/mul_1/Sum: (Sum): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/mul_1/Reshape: (Reshape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Reciprocal: (Reciprocal): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/mul: (Mul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Reciprocal_1: (Reciprocal): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/mul_1: (Mul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/sub_2/Shape: (Shape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/sub_2/Shape_1: (Shape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/sub_2/BroadcastGradientArgs: (BroadcastGradientArgs): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/sub_2/Neg: (Neg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/sub_2/Sum: (Sum): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/sub_2/Reshape: (Reshape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
AddN: (AddN): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/clip_by_value/zeros_like: (ZerosLike): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/clip_by_value/GreaterEqual: (GreaterEqual): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/clip_by_value/SelectV2: (SelectV2): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/clip_by_value/zeros_like_1: (ZerosLike): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/clip_by_value/LessEqual: (LessEqual): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/clip_by_value/SelectV2_1: (SelectV2): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/dense_2/BiasAdd/BiasAddGrad: (BiasAddGrad): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/dense_2/MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/dense_2/MatMul_1: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/dense_1/TanhGrad: (TanhGrad): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/dense_1/BiasAdd/BiasAddGrad: (BiasAddGrad): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/dense_1/MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/dense_1/MatMul_1: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/dense/Sigmoid/SigmoidGrad: (SigmoidGrad): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/dense/BiasAdd/BiasAddGrad: (BiasAddGrad): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/dense/MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/dense/MatMul_1: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/flatten/Shape: (Shape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/flatten/Reshape: (Reshape): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/max_pooling2d_2/MaxPool/MaxPoolGrad: (MaxPoolGrad): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_2/ReluGrad: (ReluGrad): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_2/BiasAdd/BiasAddGrad: (BiasAddGrad): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_2/Conv2D/ShapeN: (ShapeN): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_2/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropInput: (Conv2DBackpropInput): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_2/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropFilter: (Conv2DBackpropFilter): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/max_pooling2d_1/MaxPool/MaxPoolGrad: (MaxPoolGrad): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_1/ReluGrad: (ReluGrad): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_1/BiasAdd/BiasAddGrad: (BiasAddGrad): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_1/Conv2D/ShapeN: (ShapeN): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_1/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropInput: (Conv2DBackpropInput): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_1/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropFilter: (Conv2DBackpropFilter): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/max_pooling2d/MaxPool/MaxPoolGrad: (MaxPoolGrad): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d/ReluGrad: (ReluGrad): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d/BiasAdd/BiasAddGrad: (BiasAddGrad): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d/Conv2D/ShapeN: (ShapeN): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropInput: (Conv2DBackpropInput): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropFilter: (Conv2DBackpropFilter): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Cast/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Identity: (Identity): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/add: (AddV2): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Cast_1: (Cast): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Cast_2/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Identity_1: (Identity): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Cast_3/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Identity_2: (Identity): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Pow: (Pow): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Pow_1: (Pow): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/sub: (Sub): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Sqrt: (Sqrt): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/sub_1: (Sub): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/truediv: (RealDiv): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/mul: (Mul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/sub_2: (Sub): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/sub_3: (Sub): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Adam/update/ResourceApplyAdam: (ResourceApplyAdam): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Adam/update_1/ResourceApplyAdam: (ResourceApplyAdam): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Adam/update_2/ResourceApplyAdam: (ResourceApplyAdam): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Adam/update_3/ResourceApplyAdam: (ResourceApplyAdam): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Adam/update_4/ResourceApplyAdam: (ResourceApplyAdam): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Adam/update_5/ResourceApplyAdam: (ResourceApplyAdam): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Adam/update_6/ResourceApplyAdam: (ResourceApplyAdam): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Adam/update_7/ResourceApplyAdam: (ResourceApplyAdam): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Adam/update_8/ResourceApplyAdam: (ResourceApplyAdam): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Adam/update_9/ResourceApplyAdam: (ResourceApplyAdam): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Adam/update_10/ResourceApplyAdam: (ResourceApplyAdam): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Adam/update_11/ResourceApplyAdam: (ResourceApplyAdam): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Adam/AssignAddVariableOp: (AssignAddVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Cast_1: (Cast): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Greater: (Greater): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Cast_3: (Cast): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Equal: (Equal): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Cast_4: (Cast): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Mean: (Mean): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Sum_2: (Sum): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
AssignAddVariableOp_2: (AssignAddVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Size: (Size): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Cast_5: (Cast): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
AssignAddVariableOp_3: (AssignAddVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
div_no_nan/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
div_no_nan/ReadVariableOp_1: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
div_no_nan: (DivNoNan): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Identity: (Identity): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
div_no_nan_1/ReadVariableOp: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
div_no_nan_1/ReadVariableOp_1: (ReadVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
div_no_nan_1: (DivNoNan): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Identity_1: (Identity): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
AssignAddVariableOp_4: (AssignAddVariableOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
NoOp: (NoOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
NoOp_1: (NoOp): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Identity_2: (Identity): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Identity_3: (Identity): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
identity_2_RetVal: (_Retval): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
identity_3_RetVal: (_Retval): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
ExpandDims/dim: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
sequential/flatten/Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/Const_1: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/sub/x: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/add/y: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/sub_1/x: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/sub_2/x: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/add_1/y: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/Mean/reduction_indices: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Const_1: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Const_2: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
strided_slice/stack: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
strided_slice/stack_1: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
strided_slice/stack_2: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Const_1: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Const_2: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
ones: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/value/Shape: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/value/Shape_1: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Reshape/shape: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Reshape_1/shape: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Size: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Shape_1: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/range/start: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/range/delta: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Fill/value: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Const_1: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/Maximum/y: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/add/y: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/sub/x: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/sub_1/x: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/sub_2/x: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/sub_3/x: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam/Adam/Const: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Cast_2/x: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Mean/reduction_indices: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Const_3: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Const_4: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
7/15 [=============>................] - ETA: 1:12 - loss: 0.0874 - accuracy: 0.9498

Comment: I was not able to put this in a code in a codeblock

Answer (score 1):

Figured out why I get this output all of a sudden...
I have a piece of code at the start of training to prepare my environment, also where I can force use GPU or CPU usage. For over two years now I had been using:
`tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)`
with no logging happening at all.
Now all of a sudden tensorflow decided it was a nice idea to start logging all of it. Set it to False and all is good now!